# What is mean by Collection<? extends EmpApp>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

In my code i am using two different class objects **empobj** & **employee**.
Eclipse asks to change the code

```
empobj.addAll(employee);
```

to

```
empobj.addAll((Collection<? extends EmpApp>) employee);
```

What does it mean? 
I cannot understand the concept here.
Can I get any clarifications about this?

Comment: What is your type of `employee` , what is the signature of your `empobj.addAll()` method ? It sounds like you're adding an object to something that expects a collection

Comment: 'employee' is type of Employee, 'empobj' is type of EmpApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addAll` takes as its parameter a `Collection` and then adds all the elements of that collection to itself. In your case, you're trying to give it something that is not a `Collection`, so the compiler is trying to make it work by casting the argument to the correct type. In this particular case, the correct type is a collection of some object which extends `EmpApp`, i.e., `Collection<? extends EmpApp>`.

Judging from the name of your variable, `employee` probably isn't a collection, so you need to revisit the API for whatever collection `empobj` is and find out how you can add a single element to it (likely `add`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545183/how-to-add-an-object-into-another-object-set) asked here by me, led me here...
By your reply i cant add employee object with addall() into empobj, right. May you tell me how to over come this problem. I want to add employee objects into empobj object.

Comment: If it is jsut a single object you just call empobj.add((EmpApp)employee); rather than addAll()

Answer (score 3):

```
Collection<? extends EmpApp>
```

Is a definition of a collection. The "employee into a collection which contains objects of a class which extends EmpApp. The "?" in the generic means that Eclipse isn't sure what classname should be there.

For more on generics in Java, here's the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Answer (score 0):

A collection is group of object to be treated as a single unit.Arbitrary objects can be stored,retrieved,& manipulated as elements of collection.